# Processes being killed due to lack of memory

Tags: 16.04, process

Over the pat 2 or 3 days I've several times found my U16.04 system running, but with certain processed killed due to no memory (Syslog example below). My system has 8GB memory and when running in idle (with all normal background processes running) shows 26% memory use. This sound rather like this question: "https://askubuntu.com/questions/872188/oom-killer-is-killing-process-despite-free-memory-being-reported-on-system-monit", which has been put on hold as off-topic.

Syslog example:

```
Jan 17 07:36:18 graham-desktop kernel: [73589.744445] Out of memory: Kill process 2782 (insync) score 8 or sacrifice child
Jan 17 07:36:18 graham-desktop kernel: [73589.744472] Killed process 2782 (insync) total-vm:2684760kB, anon-rss:133684kB, file-rss:30632kB
Jan 17 07:36:20 graham-desktop kernel: [73592.460466] compiz invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x24040c0, order=3, oom_score_adj=0
Jan 17 07:36:20 graham-desktop kernel: [73592.460469] compiz cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
Jan 17 07:36:20 graham-desktop kernel: [73592.460474] CPU: 2 PID: 2360 Comm: compiz Tainted: P           OE   4.4.0-59-generic #80-Ubuntu
Jan 17 07:36:20 graham-desktop kernel: [73592.460476] Hardware name: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. To be filled by O.E.M./Z77X-D3H, BIOS F16 10/24/2012
```

Please note that Insync is only ONE of the processes being killed, and the "Kill off" doesn't stop there!

Output of free -h (with all normal processes running) is:
           total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        7.8G        1.9G        474M         63M        5.4G        5.5G
Swap:        9G         14M          9G

I'm still investigating how to use smemstat.

I've now run smemstat continuously for 2 days and detected no excessive memory use by any process. I don't think this problem is caused by any specific installed software.

Comment: Complain to whomever wrote that utility `insync` which was using almost 3 GiB of memory all by itself.

Comment: Many thanks for your off-the-cuff comment. However, Insync is only one of the processes that gets killed; other processes continue to get killed progressively after Insync. Do they all contain bugs that cause this issue? It's strange that they have all been working perfectly until the last few days, then, including Insyc (which hasn't changed in months).

Comment: The only little bit of logs you have posted show `insync` being killed. How could anybody know what else is happening on your system? I use a small Gigabyte box running Ubuntu 16.04 as a general purpose server and it stays up and happy for weeks. You may want to run `vmstat` or `free` in a loop at, I don't know, every 7th ior 17th or 117th second, and  if swap usage is excessive then write the result of `ps aux --sort -rss` to a log file and reboot the system.

Comment: smemstat can also show you the memory hogging processes

Comment: How much swap do you have set up? Type `free -h` in `terminal` to find out.

Comment: Original post edited to add free -h results.

Comment: There seems to be a recent kernel bug that was introduced with kernel 4.4.0-59: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1655842

Comment: Thanks, @Knock24, I believe you are right. Hopefully this will get resolved promptly, as I don't have the expertise to work around it.